# Rails 4: What data type should I use to save user's timezone?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to store each user's timezone in his/her profile but I'm not sure which data type I should use.

Should I add a column called "Timezone" with :string as the data type?

If I do that, should I use the options that rails provides for time zones (ie. "America/New_York")?

Or should I use :decimal and store a modifier to UTC?

Is there a gem for this?

UPDATE: I should clarify that I'm storing their preferred timezone so I can't just store timezone from the client browser in case the user travels a lot. I'll have a CRON job set up to run at midnight daily according to the user's timezone.

Comment: a standard datetime  column should allow the inclusion of a timezone too. You don't need to add an extra column for it, unless you're storing them by name for some reason. You can always just pull the timezone out of the column separately and then do a conversion to find the name of the zone.

Comment: I should clarify that I'm storing their preferred timezone so I can't just store timezone from the client browser in case the user travels a lot. I'll have a CRON job set up to run at midnight daily according to the user's preferred timezone stored in his/her profile.

Comment: Taryn, thanks for your answer. So then...I should I have a list of timezone options to select from which I then convert to the appropriate Datetime to just store it for the UTC value? Then I guess I'll use the TZInfo gem to figure daylight savings stuff. Is that the best way to go about it?

Comment: Ah right - then yeah, I'd suggest storing it as the string-representation - ie the option that you show the user in the drop-down.  Don't just use an offset or you won't be able to distinguish between cities in different countries that happen to be in the same timezone (which can be important for things like daylight savings)

Comment: Thanks, Taryn. I wish there was a gem for this. Seems like it would be a common problem. Maybe I'll make one

Comment: http://tzinfo.github.io/ ?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with help. Here's the answer:

Allow user to select preferred timezone and save the name of the timezone in his/her profile or settings wherever you're going to save it. No need for a UTC_offset column.

Rails has an array of 147 timezones:

```
 ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all
```

You can loop through each one to check the local time in that timezone. Here's one timezone for example.

```
Timezone = ActiveSupport::TimeZone[0].name
DateTime.now.in_time_zone(timezone)
```

Comment: What if I want to show different hours bassed on the choosen timezone, name will work for that?